# Add multiple new columns to a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a set of data and I need to add multiple extra columns to rank the existing data.  I am doing this by adding one extra column at a time but I was hoping for a more efficient way by passing in the columns as a character vector?  Here is a simple example:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(10),
                 y = rnorm(10))

dt[, ":=" (rank_x = rank(x, ties.method = "min"),
           rank_y = rank(y, ties.method = "min"))]
```

The ranking method is the same in all cases so I was hoping to use something like

```
cols <- c("x", "y")

dt[, cols := lapply(.SD, function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "min")), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `paste` to create new variables

```
dt[, paste0("rank_", cols) := lapply(.SD, rank, ties.method = "min"), .SDcols = cols]
```